# How to inject Hibernate SessionFactory in Spring via annotation?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-annotations

I have a Spring boot application in which I am trying to add persistence using Hibernate. I have been successfully able to add entities to the class. Now during writing the DAOs I am facing the issue that Hibernate Session Factory is not getting injected. On starting the application I receive following error :-

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'provider': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory io.xrates.backend.datamodel.dao.AbstractDao.sessionFactory; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.hibernate.SessionFactory] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@javax.inject.Inject()}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1210)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
at io.xrates.backend.Application.main(Application.java:12)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.springframework.boot.maven.RunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(RunMojo.java:418)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Interface DAO :-

```
public interface Dao<T extends Object> {
void create(T t);
T get(Serializable id);
T load(Serializable id);
List<T> getAll();
void update(T t);
void delete(T t);
void deleteById(Serializable id);
void deleteAll();
long count();
boolean exists(Serializable id);
```

}

Abstract DAO looks like :-

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils;

public class AbstractDao<T extends Object> implements Dao<T> {

    @Inject
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
    private Class<T> domainClass;

    protected Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    } 
/* other methods */
```

I have only one property file in whole application which is :-

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://<ip>/test?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true
spring.datasource.username=<username>
spring.datasource.password=<password>
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Any idea where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The spring.jpa prefix means that you're supposed to use the standard JPA API. Not the proprietary Hibernate API. Inject the EntityManager using `@PersistenceContext private EntityManager em`. The entity manager is the JPA equivalent to the Hibernate Session.

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks for your answers @JBNizet . I am new to spring and did not realise that I am actually using JPA config. Actually our plan was to not use JPA API and instead use the Hibernate API. Could you tell me how can I achieve the same using Hibernate ? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't think there is automagic support for Hibernate in Spring boot. You'll have to declare a bean in your configuration class as described in the Spring documentation: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#orm-hibernate. I would seriously reconsider your choice: the Hibernate API is old, not standard, obsolete compared to the JPA API. And using JPA would allow you to use Spring data JPA, which makes DAI implementations much simpler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still new to all these stuffs so did not understand the point that it would be good to go with JPA instead of native Hibernate. I now see your point and would go with JPA. Thanks again :)